# Iterating a nested loop consisting of two separate zip() objects. The two zip objects contain lists that have different lengths between each other

Tags: python-3.x

I have two zip objects made out of multiple lists of different lengths. How do I iterate over these two zip objects?

When I iterate over the two zip objects, it shows exactly what I think it should do. But when I iterate them in a nested for loop, it only loops once over the first for loop.

```py
listA = ["b","e","a","r"]  
listB = [1,2,3,4]  

listC = ["m","o","n","k","e","y"]  
listD = ["d","o","n","k","e","y"]  
listE = [5,6,3,8,9,10]  

"""
zipOne is a zip of listA and listB which contains lists of length 4  
zipTwo is a zip of listC, listD, and listB which contains lists of length 6
"""  

zipOne = zip(listA,listB)  
zipTwo = zip(listC,listD,listE)  

for zO in zipOne:  
    print(zO)  
    for zT in zipTwo:  
        print(zO,zT)  
        if zO[1] == zT[2]:  
            print(zT[1])
```

```py
Actual results:  
('b', 1)  
('b', 1) ('m', 'd', 5)  
('b', 1) ('o', 'o', 6)  
('b', 1) ('n', 'n', 3)  
('b', 1) ('k', 'k', 8)  
('b', 1) ('e', 'e', 9)  
('b', 1) ('y', 'y', 10)  
('e', 2)  
('a', 3)  
('r', 4)
```

Was expecting:
To iterate across the first item in zipOne and across all items in zipTwo. Then it would iterate the second item in zipOne across all items in zipTwo.
It would continue in a similar behavior until at the very end it iterates on the last zipOne item across all items in zipTwo.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is that iterating over a `zip` object exhausts the object, as it works like a generator. Example:

```
a = zip([1,2], [3,4])

for i in a:
    print(i)

 Outputs: 
  (1, 3)
  (2, 4)

for i in a:
    print(i)

 Outputs:
```

You should turn `zipTwo` into something, that is iterable, but doesn't get exhausted after iterating over it; for example a tuple:

```
zipOne = zip(listA,listB)  
zipTwo = tuple(zip(listC,listD,listE))

for zO in zipOne:  
    print(zO)  
    for zT in zipTwo:  
        print(zO,zT)  
        if zO[1] == zT[2]:  
            print(zT[1])
```

should give you the expected result.

I'm sorry, if I named something wrong; correct me, please.

Comment: @ericorvadus Then please, leave an upvote and accept the answer, so that others see, that this is solved